# Enable pan/zoom while using hovertool

Tags: bokeh

I've been trying to enable panning/zooming while the hover tool is enabled using this example - http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hover-tool. But, I can't seem to get the two to work together.

Are they mutually exclusive tools?

Comment: i don't think so. Please post a minimal example.

Comment: @colinfang, thanks for the comment. I went back and rechecked how I was specifying the tools. I corrected my mistake and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I was specifying the tools in the wrong place. Here's a working example if anyone else is trying to do the same -

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

output_file("toolbar.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        x=[1,2,3,4,5],
        y=[2,5,8,2,7],
        desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
    )
)

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("index", "$index"),
        ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
        ("desc", "@desc"),
    ]
)

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools=[hover, 'pan', 'wheel_zoom'],
           title="Mouse over the dots")

p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source)

show(p)
```